# Parse PHP data to python script

Tags: php, python, python-2.7

this is my first time coding on python, i have a nested array that i want to parse it to python where the json will be process there and return the data back to php. But since this is my first time coding on python i have no idea how to parse json data from php to python vice versa. all i know is how to run python script from php using `exec()`.

PHP

```
$alternative_val = array(
    array('1','0.5','3'),
    array('2','1','4'),
    array('0.333','0.25','1')
  );
 $json_alter = json_encode($alternative_val);

 $output = shell_exec('python test.py');
 echo $output;
```

after python receive the json data from php i should go into a list,

expected python result

```
X = [['1','0.5','3'],['2','1','4'],['0.333','0,25','1']]
print(X)
```

Comment: what is the output you getting ?

Comment: Can't you get PHP to echo `$output` in JSON format and then just have Python `json.loads` it? Do whatever, then `json.dumps` it and PHP then load that as JSON? That way there's a common format between the two and won't require custom parsing.

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha i haven't get any output since i have no idea how to parse data from php to python

Comment: @JonClements and how do i parse the json format data from php to python?

Comment: store it in a file or pass it as [arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html). If you can stringify the array you can use the json library to turn it in to json

Comment: A quick look at the manual... you've got [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)... to make your array a string... you echo that string (you'd probably need to make the python call a child process of some sort that can accept stdout as its stdin - no idea how you do that in PHP)... and then on the python side, you read the standard input, and use its [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) method...

Comment: and how do i send json data from php to python? @JonClements

Comment: Well... that's kind of a different question... you could send the data through pipes, via rpc, by temporary files, over a message queue, etc... This seems to be more a "How do I get them to understand each other if they can talk to each other" vs "How do I get them to talk to each other?"... It'd help if you gave more context of what you're trying to do and why and what the data between the two would be etc.... that'd at least give a chance of narrowing the scope of the question as at the moment it's very much a "it all depends..."

Comment: @JonClements i've edited my post... any method that easy to understand for beginner are really helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use json_encode function for your php script and modify your shell command with arguments. And after that you will get your json data in py script.

PHP:

```
 $alternative_val = array(
    array('1','0.5','3'),
    array('2','1','4'),
    array('0.333','0.25','1')
 );
 $json_alter = json_encode($alternative_val);

 $output = shell_exec('python test.py "' . $json_alter . '"');
 echo $output;
```

PYTHON:

```
import sys
x = sys.argv[1]
print(x)
```